# pyTelegramBotAPI: Как передать message.chat.id в другую функцию

Tags: python, функции, переменные, telebot

Как можно передать message.chat.id в другую функцию?

```
import telebot
import config
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

def create_folders():
    try:
        os.makedirs(user_folder + "/" + str(message.chat.id) + "/" + "result")
    except:
        pass

@bot.message_handler(commands=["dirs"])
def update_email_field(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Создание папок")
    create_folders()

bot.polling()
```

Comment: добавьте аргумент для этой функции и передавайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import telebot
import config
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

def create_folders(chat_id):
    try:
        os.makedirs(user_folder + "/" + str(chat_id) + "/" + "result")
    except:
        pass

@bot.message_handler(commands=["dirs"])
def update_email_field(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Создание папок")
    create_folders(message.chat.id)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Блин, так просто, спасибо